# VelocyPack VPackParser returns null _key from toJson method

Tags: java, arangodb

I have the following document in a collection named test:

```
[
  {
    "_key": "2469",
    "_id": "test/2469",
    "_rev": "_Ujegqfu---",
    "fieldName": "some value"
  }
]
```

I'm retrieving this with the following two methods:

```
public Result helloWorldJson() {

    ArangoDB db = new ArangoDB.Builder().user("<user>").password("<pass>").build();
    VPackParser parser = new VPackParser() ;

    VPackSlice slice = db.db("<db>").collection("test").getDocument("2469", VPackSlice.class);      
    String json = db.db("cms").collection("test").getDocument("2469", String.class);

    return Results.text().render("{velocy: " + parser.toJson(slice, true) + ", json: " + json);
}
```

Which produces this output:

```
{velocy: {"_key":"2469","_id":null,"_rev":"_Ujegqfu---","fieldName":"some value"}, json: {"_key":"2469","_id":"test\/2469","_rev":"_Ujegqfu---","fieldName":"some value"}
```

Does the VPackParser leave the `_id` null on purpose or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `_id` field in stored documents is from a special velocypack type which isn't supported by Json and inlcudes the collection-id, the document is stored in.
To correctly deserialize this field in the human readable "collection-name/document-key" the deserialization process needs to know the collection-name of the given collection-id. This is only possible if the process can call the database or the internal collection-cache of the java-driver. Only when you call getDocument(String,Type) or another API method the deserialization process has access to this. `VPackParser` is a standalone Velocypack<->Json parser which isn't able to resolve the field `_id`.

```
String json = db.db("cms").collection("test").getDocument("2469", String.class);
```

As in your call, when you set `type` to `String` the method `toJson()` on an instance of `VPackParser` is used which has access to the dabase and the collection-cache and so can correctly desialize the field `_id` when parsing the velocypack to json.

If you want to deserialize a Velocypack separately from an api call (with correct parsing of `_id`) you can use the class `ArangoUtil` which you get from the method `util()` on `ArangoDB`,`ArangoDatabase` or `ArangoCollection`.

```
VPackSlice slice = db.db("<db>").collection("test").getDocument("2469", VPackSlice.class);
String json = db.util().deserialize(slice, String.class);
```

Comment: Thanks. Does the driver use velocy to transport regardless of how you deserialize?

Comment: Yes. Everything is serialized/deserialized to/from Velocypack and transported with the binary protocol Velocystream.